# How does vary the brightness of markers on a Matplotlib basemap?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This code varies the transparency of markers on a matplotlib base map via the alpha parameter.

```
myBaseMap.plot(x_values, y_values, 'x', alpha=0.7, c=(1.,0,0))
```

However, how does one vary the brightness of a marker? I do not want semi-transparent markers because I want the markers to cover the content behind them. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reading of your question is that you would like to know how to get different transparency for line and markers.

One way to do this is to plot the markers using `scatter`:

```
myBaseMap.plot(x_values, y_values, alpha=0.7, c=(1.,0,0), zorder=0)
myBaseMap.scatter(x_values, y_values, marker='x', color=(1.,0,0), zorder=1)
```

Lower `zorder` numbers are drawn first.

Simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[3,2,1],alpha=0.25,c=(1.,0,0),zorder=0)
plt.scatter([1,2,3],[3,2,1],marker='x',color=(1.,0,0),zorder=1,s=75,alpha=1.0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that let me impose markers on each other and specify which ones go in the front.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to vary the brightness, like dark red versus light red, then you could linearly vary the color from (0,0,0), which is black, to (1,0,0), which is red, to (1,1,1), which is white, leaving alpha alone.

But I'm not very sure this is what you want...